# Storyboard Segue vs Delegation. Which method is better for passing data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, model-view-controller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm completely new in iOS and wondering which method to use to pass data between ViewControllers. I prefer segues because using just a line of code you are getting the reference to a ViewController and its fields, methods etc... On the other hand, delegation is an important topic in ios. And I'm now confused which method to use. Please explain me.

Comment: Apples and oranges. Honestly. For starters, you *cannot* use segues unless you are defining them in a storyboard. Once you get that, you need to ask yourself *how* is the next view controller being used - presented, child controller, what? And that doesn't even mention *why* you are passing this "data".... Is it to "segue" from one master view to the next? Maybe to "inform" or "trigger" an action in a controller of another view? In other words - what is your **specific** issue?

Comment: They serve different purpose, unless you are asking specific Unwind segue vs delegation, then you should google it first

Answer (score 0):

**Take my answer very carefully, it highly depends on what architecture (MVC, MVP, VIPER, etc) you are using and in the way your code is organized**

---

The answer is: Depending on what you want to achieve.

**Segue**

When you need to pass data from one UIViewController to another so it can be properly rendered you will use segues. They are a really straightforward way to do so.

**Delegation**

When you need to make an object (e.g., UIViewController) aware of the actions occurring in another object (e.g., another UIViewController) you can use delegation (among others) to achieve this.

Comment: Delegation is a pattern for extending the functionality of class without changing its source, i.e. textbook example of a pattern supporting the open-closed principle. Not just for notifying objects of events. E.g. in UIKit we see delegation methods like "height for row at index path", "view for header in section", "should do this", "should do that", and other methods that lets you customise the appearance and behaviours of the controls without changing their source.

Comment: @JohnSnow agreed, however, in the context of the question I did not see the need of naming the full use of the delegation pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic behaviour of these two. I am including Notification as well so that you can distinguish between Delegation and Notification. You will be pretty much using Notification in the future :
**Segue** : Simplest way when you have to send across some data from one `UIViewController` to other. **VC! -> VC2**. Remember, VC2 should be the next in the navigation hierarchy.
**Delegation** : Used to notify an object when an event has triggered. Example - Getting data from API. Display activityIndication when data is being received. Hide it when API has completed it's job. This behaviour can be very easily implemented using Blocks or Closures.
*Note* : This is useful when you have to notify just one object.
**Notification** : Used to notify an object(s) when an event has triggered.
*Note* : This is used to notify one or more than one object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm avoding delegation. I'm using closure for send data from VC2 to VC1, and set values from VC1 to VC2.
Don't forget use NavigationController in storyboard or in code

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
  var someValue1:Bool = false

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    showVC2()
  }

  func showVC2() {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "PlaceTrackList", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! TrackListViewController
    vc.completionClosure { [weak self] someValueFromVC2 in
      // close when button tapped in VC2 and set value like in VC2
      self?.someValue1 = someValueFromVC2
      self?.navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }


class VC2: UIViewController {
  var someValue2:Bool = true
  completionClosure: ((Bool) -> Void)?

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func VC2ButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
    completionClosure?(someValue2)
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**in terms of data passing**

it depends on where you want to pass the data if you want to pass the data from VC1 to VC2 than segue is useful but if you want to transfer data from VC2 to VC1 then this is something that you won't be able to achieve with segues for that you can use a delegate.

**in general terms**

**delegate** - a delegate is a way of communication between to objects like table view delegate methods in which you will be notified when a cell is touched